# How to remove bar (Android Studio)

Tags: android

I am learning Android Studio and I made my first app. When I run it, there is a bar (is it a right name for it?) that I don't want (this with three dots on the right). How to remove it? I was trying with changing AndroidManifest.xml android:theme but app started crashing.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKJsI.png

Answer (score 3):

In styles.xml, select a theme with no action bar.
For example

```
Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar
```

Also

1) exend your class from Activity instead of ActionBarActivity

2) remove method onCreateOptionsMenu (if present) from your activty

3) remove method onOptionsItemSelected (if present) from your activity

Comment: These are unnecessary steps...its a pain to add those things back if you suddenly found out that you need to have the menu back....removing the `onCreateOptionsMenu` will suffice

Comment: Dude read the question. He needs to remove the entire action bar. See the image he attached.

Answer (score 1):

In the Android Manifest change the theme to the following

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

Comment: Please don't use the action bar anymore. Try to use the Toolbar added as a part of material design

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but i am confused that whether you want to remove the whole bar (ActionBar) or you want to remove the "three dots (menu)" on the right of the bar...
If you want to remove the whole bar then try this:
Put this under your activity tag in android manifest

```
     `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"`
```

and if you want to remove those three dots then "Saeid Yazdani" is right.

Answer (score 0):

Your activity likely extends ActionBarActivity and the OnCreateOptionsMenu method is created by default.

To note, you should put the Activity back into the Manifest and edit the Actvity Java class file.